# opencv cmake warning meanings: CMakeLists.txt:1066 (include)

Tags: opencv

I am now building from source the `opencv4.1.0` with `cmake3.13`. The cmake configuration gives a warning message saying:

```
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVGenSetupVars.cmake:54 (message):
  CONFIGURATION IS NOT SUPPORTED: validate setupvars script in install
  directory
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1066 (include)
```

What does this warning mean? Does that need be carefully addressed for starting the building process?

Answer (score 3):

check the file cmake/OpenCVGenSetupVars.cmake

```
if(DEFINED __python_path)
  if(IS_ABSOLUTE "${__python_path}")
    set(OPENCV_PYTHON_DIR_RELATIVE_CMAKECONFIG "${__python_path}")
    message(WARNING "CONFIGURATION IS NOT SUPPORTED: validate setupvars script in install directory")
```

It seems like you have set your Python path wrong

Answer (score 0):

In windows you have to make an relative path in environtment settings to python/libs/site-packages. So in cmake set PYTHON3_SITE_PACKAGES to the relative path e.g %PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES%.

And remember to run cmake / visual studio as administrator.