# Problems building openCV with contrib using CMake in windows for visual studio 2019

Tags: python, visual-studio, opencv, cmake, opencv-contrib

I am having trouble building openCV (I need to use the contribs libraries) in windows for visual studio 2019. I am a bit confused as to how this works - I have python 3 installed via anaconda 3 and I am getting the following error:

*CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVGenSetupVars.cmake:54 (message):
  CONFIGURATION IS NOT SUPPORTED: validate setupvars script in install
  directory
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:967 (include)*

It also tests for python 2 and python 3 do I need both installed?

I have my system environment variable set to C:\DEV\anaconda3\Library\bin

When I try to build the project I get thousands of errors in visual studio.

Link to another similar question:

[opencv cmake warning meanings: CMakeLists.txt:1066 (include)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56606865/opencv-cmake-warning-meanings-cmakelists-txt1066-include/62281779?noredirect=1#comment110150085_62281779)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it in the end. Anaconda uses python 3.7 which doesn't seem to work on opencv4.3. I changed my opencv version to 4.2 and managed to get everything compiling in the end.

The warning itself is still there, but it is now building successfully.